# How to compare the elements of a nested list?

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I have some kind of matrix: 
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[0,2,1],[1,2,3]] and I would like to be able to determine how many times I have the sequence 1,2,3 diagonally, vertically and horizontally but I have problems of index out of range for the last two loops. Thank you in advance for your answers!!

```
lista = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[0,2,1],[1,2,3]]
compteur_horizontal = 0
for i in range(len(lista)):
    for c in range(len(lista[i])-2):
        if lista[i][c] == 1 and lista[i][c+1] == 2 and lista[i][c+2] == 3:
            compteur_horizontal += 1
            print("ok")

compteur_vertical = 0
for c in range(len(lista)):
    for j in range(len(lista[c])):
        print(lista[j][c])

compteur_diagonale = 0
for j in range(len(lista)):
    print(lista[i][i])
```

For the first counter, I would like it to be 3 since we have 3 times the sequence 1,2,3 horizontally. For the second counter, I would like it to be 0 because vertically there is no 1,2,3 sequence. And  I'm waiting for a counter with 0 also since there's no 1,2,3 sequence in diagonal

Comment: Try `if lista[i][c] == 1` (i.e. without the quotes

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Thank you very much, I hadn't noticed! Unfortunately, it doesn't change my problem.

Comment: Please say what the outcome should be for such input

Comment: @Pynchia For the first counter, I would like it to be 3 since we have 3 times the sequence 1,2,3 horizontally. For the second counter, I would like it to be 0 because vertically there is no 1,2,3 sequence. And since I didn't know how to find the diagonal, I didn't create a counter but now I'm waiting for a counter with 0 also since there's no 1,2,3 sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will not work even if you correct the current error. You need to change j and c in the second loop to resolve the error.

For horizontal and vertical here's the code. I'll add how to count diagonal ones later.

```
#lista = [[1, 2, 3],[1, 2, 3],[0, 2, 1],[1, 2, 3]]
lista = [[1,2,2],
         [1,2,4],
         [4,2,3],
         [5,6,3]]
ptrn = [1, 2, 3]

# returns True is lst (1d array) has ptrn (1d array).
# e.g. lst[1,2,4,6,1,2,3,7], ptrn=[1,2,3] return True
# e.g. lst[1,2,4,6,1,4,3,7], ptrn=[1,2,3] return False
def is_pattern_in_a_list(lst, ptrn):
    if ptrn[0] in lst:
        idx = lst.index(ptrn[0])
        for i in range(1, len(ptrn)):
            if idx + i < len(lst):
                if ptrn[i] != lst[idx+i]:
                    return False
            else:
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False

# counting horizontal occurances
count_h = 0
for row in lista:
    if is_pattern_in_a_list(row, ptrn):
        count_h += 1

# counting vertical occurances
# we first transpose the 2d array and use the same
# method of counting horizontal occurances.

def transpose_2d_array(a):
    return [[a[j][i] for j in range(len(a))] for i in range(len(a[0]))]

lista_transpose = transpose_2d_array(lista)

count_v = 0
for row in lista_transpose:
    if is_pattern_in_a_list(row, ptrn):
        count_v += 1

# for diagonal occurances first we need to extract the diagonals 
# with len >= len(ptrn).

# diagonals for the upper right triangle of the matrix:
count_d = 0
for i in range(len(lista[0])):
    diag = []
    j = 0
    k = i
    while j < len(lista)-i and k < len(lista[0]):
        diag.append(lista[j][k])
        j += 1
        k += 1
    if is_pattern_in_a_list(diag, ptrn):
        count_d += 1

# diagonals for the lower left triangle of the matrix
i = len(lista) - 1
while i >= 1:
    j = i
    k = 0
    diag = []
    while j < len(lista) and k <= len(lista)+1-i:
        diag.append(lista[j][k])
        j += 1
        k += 1
    i -= 1

    if is_pattern_in_a_list(diag, ptrn):
        count_d += 1

    print(diag)

print("Horizontal %d" % count_h)
print("Vertical %d" % count_v)
print("Diagonal %d" % count_d)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to correct my code!

Comment: Please note that this code only counts \ diagonal occurances and does not count / diagonals.